# If the Mu'adhdhin makes a mistake while calling the adhan, does he have to start over from the beginning?

Tags: fiqh, adhan, mistake

If the Mu'adhdhin makes a mistake while calling the adhan,and someone subhanallah him, does he have to start over from the beginning? And, can you inform me on what school did you get your fiqh from or what haddith did you use to get your answer. Thank you. Assalamu Alaykum.

Comment: It depends on the kind of mistake, and how would a mu'adhin in a minaret hear someone saying subhan Allah in a mosque? A Mua'dhin should call for prayer in a place where his voice can be heard far outside the mosque too! It's not permitted to use speakers while you are inside the mosque for this purpose.